# Connecting to mongodb on a remote server from R

Tags: python, r, mongodb, ssh

I have been trying to find answers to connect to the MongoDB which sits on the server(Linux) from my local windows machine. I have stumbled upon answers like use packages such as RMongo and Mongolite. But they seem to work when I want to connect to MongoDB that is on my local machine on localhost. I know how to do it in python by using SSHTunnel to connect to the server and then use pymongo to play with MongoDB. I am looking for python equivalent workaround for R. The python code is as follows:

```
mongo_host = ''
mongo_user = ''
mongo_pass = ''    

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        mongo_host,
        ssh_username = mongo_user,
        ssh_password=mongo_pass,
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
        ) 
server.start()   
client = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1',server.local_bind_port)
db = client.myDB
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mongolite package you should be able to access your db via its' URL:

```
mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost",
verbose = FALSE, options = ssl_options())
```

See ?mongolite